# how to refresh a service

Tags: android, service

can anyone tell me that in android how can we refresh a service??

i am developing an app in which my service  is running perfectly and giving me data what i want..BUT each and every time it is giving me same data which it giving on first time i.e. service starting time.
after that it is running but that data is stic with that old data ,so i want to know is there any way to refresh service so any time as data changed it give me fresh data or any other way?

thanks in advance..

Comment: You should provide more information.  How is your data being stored and returned by the service.  Code is helpful.

Comment: hi my problem got solved thanks

Answer (score 1):

use AlarmManager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html